# Mosquitto WebSocket service is not exposed using docker-compose

Tags: websocket, docker-compose, mqtt

i'm running docker-compose.yaml with the configuration for mosquitto:

```
mosquitto:
  image: eclipse-mosquitto
  ports:
    - 1883:1883
    - 9001:9001

  volumes:
    - ./configuration/mosquitto:/mosquitto/config/
    - ./configuration/mosquitto/logs:/var/log/mosquitto
```

I can see the following log when I run docker-compose:

```
1653666208: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting

1653666208: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.

1653666208: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.

1653666208: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.

1653666208: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
```

I can access the TCP on 1883, But I can't see the WebSocket service running on the server.
I tried the

```
sudo netstat -lnp| grep 9001
```

and it didn't return me anything.

What am I missing in the configuration?

Comment: Netstat will not show anything because the port is being forwarded via iptables. What do the logs site when you try and connect a WebSocket client?

Comment: what do u mean? i'm not using browser. The javascript client give me the following error: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.16.8.179:9001
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.16.8.179',
  port: 9001
}`

Comment: Docker ports are normally exposed via an iptables port forwarding rule on the host machine. Edit the question to add a lot more detail about where you are running the client and include your mosquitto config file

Comment: Resolved. The config of mosquito is: 
listener 1883
listener 9001
the problem was that I was reloading docker-compose using VS tool and it seems that it didn't pick up the changes made in the .yaml file. Stopping it from the terminal and launching again make it works.